# How to pass in multiple arguments to execute with .sh script

Tags: linux, shell-script, arguments

I have a **list.txt** file including a list of log file.

For example

```
    server_log1
    server_log2
    ........
    server_log50
```

I have another shell script used to download these logs. It worked like this

```
./script.sh serverlog1
```

I want to make it automatically that means it can automatically pass in each log file's name in **list.txt** to be executed.

Is that possible?
I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /home/ec2-user/list.txt` ; do
sh ./workaround.sh $i
done
```

But it didn't work

Comment: sidenote: don't use file extensions for executables (scripts etc). If you re-write in python, C, or what ever, then you don't want to have to change the file name, as it will cause you to change every script that uses it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest method for reading arguments can be described as follows;

Each argument is referenced and parsed by the `$IFS` or currently defined `internal file separator`. The default character is a space.

For example, take the following; `# ./script.sh arg1 arg2`

The argument list in that example is `arg1 = $1` and `arg2 = $2` which can be rewritten as `arg1 arg2 = $@`.

Another note is the use of a list of logs, how often does that change? My assumption is daily. Why not use the directory output as the array of your iterative loop? For example;

```
for i in $(ls /path/to/logs); do
  ./workaround.sh $i;
done
```

Or better yet, move on to use of `functions` in bash to eliminate clutter.

```
function process_file()
{
  # transfer file code/command
}

function iterate_dir()
{
  local -a dir=($(ls $1))
  for file in ${dir[@]}; do
    process_file $file
  done
}

iterate_dir /path/to/log/for
```

While these are merely suggestions to improve your shell scripting knowledge I must know if there is an error you are getting and would also need to know the details of each scripts code and or functionality. Making the use of the `-x` argument helps debug scripting as well.

If you are simply transferring logs you may wish to do away with the scripts all together and make use of `rsync`, `rsyslog` or `syslog` as they all are much more suited for the task in question.

Comment: `$@` is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
xargs -n 1 ./script.sh <list.txt
```

In this example, `xargs` will execute `./script.sh` multiple times with a single argument read from its standard input.

The standard input comes from the file `list.txt` via a simple shell input redirection.  This assumes that the `list.txt` file contains one argument to use with the script per line.

The `./script.sh` script will be executed once for each line in the `list.txt` file.

---

About the `-n` flag to `xargs`

> `-n number`
>
> Invoke *utility* using as many standard input arguments as
>                    possible, up to `number` (a positive decimal integer) arguments
>                   maximum.

---

Another solution would be to allow the script to read directly from `list.txt`, or to take multiple command line argument (the entries from `list.txt`), and to download the files in one or several batches.  But since we don't know what the mechanics of the script is, I can't make any detailed explanation of how to go about doing this.

Comment: You might want to explain the syntax you use a bit in your answer, since this seems like a bit of a newbie asking. Otherwise great answer, I'd say this is probably the best way to do it VS `while read`

Comment: @Centimane Are you referring to the redirection, or to the semantics of `-n 1`? There's not much of syntax to explain...

Comment: I would do both, but maybe that's just me. I'd quote the `man` page for the `-n` option and a sentence or two on the redirection.

Answer (score 2):

inside the script : you need a read loop  like `while read ; do ......... ; done < filename` to treat lines as $REPLY variable...

for example

```
while read 
do
mv $REPLY $REPLY.old
done < liste.txt
```

will rename any filename from inside liste.txt to filename.old

you have the structure now you can adapt to your needs depending on what you mean by *" in each log file's name in list.txt to be executed."*  :)

Comment: Can you please check my latest code?

Answer (score 2):

(**Note:** I personally think [Kusalananda's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425875/243481) is the best in this specific scenario, so I'll just add some explanatory information and recommendations)

---

### Don't read lines with `for`

Using that approach you:

- Rely on [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) to make things work.
- Are subject of unintended side effects like [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
- Slurp the entire file into memory all at once (may be a problem with big files).

The `while` + `read` approach is preferable but [it is not a bullet-proof solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/243481):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Your code here
done < file
```

### Quote your variables

Write `"$i"` instead of `$i`. Unquoted variables are probably the main source of bugs and security holes in shell scripts.

Related questions:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/243481)

### Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``

`$(...)` is POSIX-compliant and can be nested easier.

---

You could also modify your script to support multiple arguments and even a `--batch` option.

If you don't know where to start, [I have a sample/template script which supports those features](https://gist.github.com/nxnev/dae306158fc65471172c5814b49aad35) (it uses Bash-specific syntax, though).

Example of usage:

```
$ cat list.txt
list_item_1
list_item_2
list_item_3
$ script --batch list.txt item_1 item_2
Operands:
  1: [list_item_1]
  2: [list_item_2]
  3: [list_item_3]
  4: [item_1]
  5: [item_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i read this question incorrectly but the way I read it was how to get my personal script to take multiple arguments the way for example wget can perform "wget url1 url2 url3"

paste your entire script inside the following where it says "lines from my script" and save this file as your new script.:

```
ARGUMENTS=$(echo "$@"| tr " " "\n") ; while read A; do "lines from my script";done < "$ARGUMENTS"
```

Note if your script refers to $1 you will have to change that to $A, and of course check any other references.

arguments are stored in one line space separated in a variable called $@.
this hack uses tr to trade the spaces with a new line and stores that in a new variable called ARGUMENTS.  the rest of the script runs your script for each line of that variable.

I wrote this to get my bash web scraper which accepts ONE and only one argument to accept multiple urls, so it may not work with scripts that normally accept more than one argument